# Сумма порядковых номеров букв (ABCM: 1 + 2 + 3 +13 = 19)

Tags: javascript, массивы

Дан массив JavaScript: `[Natasha, Device, Auto, ...................]`
Нужна сумма порядковых номеров букв алфавита, пример (ABCM: 1 + 2 + 3 +13 = 19)
Мой код:

```
const nameArr = ['mary']; // 13 + 1 + 18 + 25 = 57


const alphabet= {
    'a':  1, 'b':  2, 'c':  3, 'd':  4, 'e':  5, 'f':  6, 'g':  7, 'h': 8,  'i':  9,
    'j': 10, 'k': 11, 'l': 12, 'm': 13, 'n': 14, 'o': 15, 'p': 16, 'q': 17, 'r': 18,
    's': 19, 't': 20, 'u': 21, 'v': 22, 'w': 23, 'x': 24, 'y': 25, 'z': 26
};
```

Comment: Как первое предложение связано со вторым?

Comment: тут одно предложение

Comment: Сделай двумерный массив соответствия буква-число на весь алфавит. Разбирай слова по буквам, ищи в массиве номер буквы и складывай.

Comment: @skos99 Тут четыре предложения.

Comment: Хорошо бы код выкладывать.  А то это очередной вопрос - сделай за меня! И не хватает условий. Будет только кириллица или латиница, а может оба варианта?

Comment: @KonstantinEmelyanov: вредные у Вас какие-то советы

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что понимаю, при чём здесь упомянутый в начале массив. Но если нужна функция пересчёта строки в сумму порядковых номеров букв по алфавиту и если ожидается только базовая латиница, можно так:

```js
'use strict';

function getAlphabetSum(str) {
  return [...str].map(char => char.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 96)
                 .reduce((acc, num) => acc + num);
}

console.log(getAlphabetSum('ABcd')); // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
```

Comment: Если вам нужно упомянутый массив строк превратить в массив сумм, останется только применить `.map()`:
`arrayOfSums = arrayOfStrings.map(getAlphabetSum);`

Answer (score 1):

Немного поиграюсь, пожалуй - всего 47 символов на преобразование строки в сумму:

```js
console.log(["Natasha","Device","Auto","ABCM"].map(
  s=>eval(s.replace(/./g,'+parseInt("$&",36)-9'))
))
```